# I need to stop my page from refreshing with simple javascript

Tags: javascript

So I've typed this all, and the only thing that would make this code perfect, is a no refresh code. I need it to be in Javascript, no Jquery, Ajax, or PHP. Because I don't understand those languages yet. Well, here is my code.

```
function welkom()//this function is in the <body onload="">
{
var naam = prompt("Wat is je naam");
document.getElementById("welkom").innerHTML="Welkom " + naam + " en succes    met de tafels.";
}
function test()//this function is in the <body onload="">
{
    var nummer = document.getElementById("cijfers").value;
    document.getElementById("resultaat").innerHTML = "";
    var form = "<table><form>";
    for (var x = 1;x<=10;x++)
    {
        form += "<tr><td>" + x + "x" + nummer + "= </td>";
        form += "<td><input type='text' id='vraag[" + x + "]' /></td></tr>";
    }
    form += "</table><input type='submit' value='Controleer je antwoorden' onclick='controleer()'></form>";
    document.getElementById("resultaat").innerHTML = form;
}
        function controleer()//this is the function that refreshes my page.
        {
            var tafelNr = document.getElementById("cijfers").value;
            var goed = 0;
            var fout = 0;

            for (var teller=1;teller<=10;teller++)
            {
                var tafelNr = document.getElementById("cijfers").value;
                var goedantwoord = tafelNr * teller;
                var antwoord = document.getElementById("vraag[" + teller + "]").value;

                if (goedantwoord == antwoord)
                {
                    document.getElementById("vraag[" + teller + "]").style.backgroundColor="#00ff00";
                    goed++
                }
                else
                {
                    document.getElementById("vraag[" + teller + "]").style.backgroundColor="#ff0000";
                    fout++
                }
            }
            if (goed <=6)
            {
                alert("Je had " + goed + " vragen goed en " + fout + " vragen fout. \nVraag aan de meester of juf om een oefenblaadje.");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Je had " + goed + " vragen goed en " + fout + " vragen fout. \nGoed gedaan!")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to avoid refresh? Is is because your page is getting resubmitted on refresh?

Answer (score 1):

Change `onclick='controleer()'` to `onclick='controleer(); return false;'`

Alternatively, don't use a `<form>` if you don't intend for it to submit data.